# TS Language server for custom types

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I’m working on a project that has many, many hundreds of classes that are on a remote server. I have a way to get these class definitions via a web service that gives me XML, and I have a way to repackage those classes as Typescript declarations. I work with legacy software that uses server side jscript / es3.

In order to have intellisense I currently pull all of the application’s classes, run them through my pipeline and turn them into TS declarations that I can use with vscode’s jsdoc type annotations.

If I want my team to share in this bounty though, or if I work with other developers on the application and types/classes change on the server, then it would be awesome if I could just have vscode consume a service that would always be up to date and not have to keep updating declaration files.

Would I need to extend vscode’s tsserver, or roll my own? Ideally I’d have this as an extension that my team could just install. I’m just hung up on the best approach.

Thanks!

Comment: I would stick with generating the definitions and sticking them in souece control. Maybe have something that regenerates them automatically when the server definitions change. Anything else is overkill IMO.